# Como inserir variável em html gerado por javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

O problema que tenho é o seguinte. Tenho um código que gera vários resultados em html para mim. Só que preciso de um detalhe que não consegui implementar. O código é o seguinte:

```
$('#avaliacoes').append('\<div class=\'estrelas\'><input type=\'radio\' id=\'cm_star-empty\' name=\'fb\' value\'\'/>
```

A partir do de um outro código, eu obtenho uma variável resultante de um foreach. O nome dela é **resultado[i].Nome**

A única coisa que preciso, é inserir essa variável e **concatenar com o valor do atributo name** da tag input.

*Como posso fazer isso usando o append acima?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O teu HTML tem alguns erros... mas podes fazer isso assim:

```
var resultado = [{
    Nome: 'Ana'
}, {
    Nome: 'Maria'
}];
var html = resultado.reduce(function(string, pessoa) {
    return string + [
    '<div class=\'estrelas\'><input type=\'radio\' id=\'cm_star-empty\' name=\'fb_', 
    pessoa.Nome, 
    '\' value=\'\'/></div>'
    ].join('');
}, '');
$('#avaliacoes').append(html);
```

que vai dar:

```
<div class="estrelas"><input type="radio" id="cm_star-empty" name="fb_Ana" value=""></div>
<div class="estrelas"><input type="radio" id="cm_star-empty" name="fb_Maria" value=""></div>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d9fycaz2/1

Corrigi a falta de `=` no `value` e a falta de `</div>`. Se fizeres essa string começar com aspas, em vêz de plicas, a já não precisas de escapar o HTML.

Comment: Tudo certinho, vlw Sergio!

Comment: @DiChrist ótimo. Agora quando olhei para a resposta de novo modifiquei por outra maneira que gosto ainda mais. Assim não vai chamar `$('#avaliacoes')` vezes a mais sem necessidade.

Comment: @Sergio O `return + [...`, o que faz ao certo. Não consigo testar agora mas estou curioso

Comment: @Miguel a função `Array.reduce` precisa que a callback dê retorno. Nessa linha estou a retornar a string acumulada com a nova  que constru-o com uma aray e um `.join('')` no final para concatenar.

Answer (score 0):

Na minha opinião, evite misturar html com javascrip...

```js
var resultado = [{
  Nome: 'Ana'
}, {
  Nome: 'Maria'
}];
var divClone = null;
var children = null
resultado.forEach(function(pessoa) {
  divClone = $('#divClone').clone();
  children = $(divClone).children();
  children[0].name = 'fb_' + pessoa.Nome;
  divClone[0].children = children;
  divClone[0].id = '';
  $(divClone).removeClass('hide');
  $('#avaliacoes').append(divClone);
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="avaliacoes">
  <div class='estrelas hide' id='divClone'>
    <input type='radio' id='cm_star-empty' name="" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Segue o exemplo no  JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/d9fycaz2/7/